# How to dismiss a movie-player view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, media-player

Hey, i am trying to make an iphone app where you click on a cell in UITableView and it brings up a movie on whatever you clicked on. so far i have allready gotten it to:

1. Have a UITableView
2. load a nib file when you click on a cell

but i still need help with making the movie go away and goto the main nib file when you hit done

i have tried using a notofication like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
    initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(leave) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

and this is how i got my movie to load on IOS 4.0

```
-(IBAction)PlayMovie
{
    NSString *movpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"mov"];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                                     initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movpath]];
                                                        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 target:self selector:@selector(leave) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
    [window addSubview:mpviewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [mpviewController moviePlayer];
    [mp prepareToPlay];
    mp.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;

    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:)
    //                                           name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification
    //                                         object:mp];

    [[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
}
```

please help

~thanks

Comment: i don't know if this works, or if it is allowed. so.. Bump.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is he code template you should use, and it supposed to work and dismiss your movie when the movie finished playing.

```
- (void)playMovie {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                      pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"m4v"];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
              initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedPlaying:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
     object:[player moviePlayer]];


    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];

}


-(void) movieFinishedPlaying: (NSNotification *) note {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
     object:[player moviePlayer]];

    [player release];
}
```